# How to anti-alias in DirectX11 with Flip mode?

Tags: directx, directx-11

I understand that the flip presentation mode (`DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD`) is recommended but it does not seem to support multi-sampling. So how can you do anti-aliasing ?

Comment: [Multisampling in Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/multisampling--multi-sample-anti-aliasing--in-windows-store-apps)

Comment: @user7860670 For a non-UWP desktop app is there any reason to do this over just not using flip mode?

Comment: Well, if support for flip model (and benefits that it brings) is not required, then probably none.

Comment: @user7860670 I thought the benefit of the flip mode was only that you didn't perform a surface copy on present. But if you need to perform a surface copy to do AA then I'm not seeing any reason for flip mode.

Comment: Multisampling AA works by rendering several pixels per render target pixel and calculating average value so it is essentially equivalent to surface copy. They've just separated it into two steps. I think this form of separation is also used with Nvidia DLSS and similar techniques. (at least that's how i see it)

Comment: My point is that AA seems to defeat any benefit from flip mode.

Comment: While my point is the with AA you'll need to perform an extra surface copy regardless of whether flip mode is used or not. The only difference is that without flip mode surface copy for AA is performed implicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modern "flip" modes (`DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD` and `DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL`) enforce some new usage rules. Specifically you can't create an MSAA backbuffer or an `_SRGB` format backbuffer.

The reality is that when using the legacy "blt" style modes (`DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD`, `DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_SEQUENTIAL`), you can't really create an MSAA backbuffer at all. It just implicitly created a single-sample backbuffer and a MSAA render target, and did the resolve "by magic".

In most 'real world' rendering solutions, you (a) don't just do a resolve, and (b) don't immediately render the resolved content of the MSAA render target. Post-processing, custom anti-aliasing, and post-resolve UI composition all takes place before you Present the result. As such, the 'magic' solution is only useful for trivial samples.

See this blog series: [The Care and Feeding of Modern Swap Chains](https://walbourn.github.io/care-and-feeding-of-modern-swapchains/)